# PHP Script Not Receiving POST Variable sent by JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post

Here's the code (already imported the JQuery):

```
$.post("check.php", { username: usr },
    function(result)
    {
        //if the result is 1
        if(result == 1)
        {
            //show that the username is available
            $('#ck_usr_rslt').html(username + ' is Available');
        }
        else
        {
            //show that the username is NOT available
            $('#chk_usr_rslt').html(username + ' is not Available');
        }
});
```

The thing is, my check.php script keeps throwing the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RP/check.php on line 23
```

(Line 23 is when is calls $_POST['username'])

So what's wrong? Could it be the local server I'm running that's the problem? Or is it just some mistake of mine in the JavaScript?

Comment: Can you please post the PHP as well?

Comment: try uploading your code to an actual sever and not just your localhost. let me know if this works.

Comment: Can we take a look at the whole line 23 you're talking about? can you share it? Also. Did you make sure the variable "usr" is not null? Share your line 23 because from what I see at the moment you're doing the right thing

Comment: How do you get variable usr? It might be empty.

Comment: Look at javascript console for errors, if there are none then look at the network tab to see if the data is being sent. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: @jrubins It fails even when I just use `echo isset($_POST['username']);` @eburg The line of code on line 23 is `$usr = $_POST['username'];` @Noah Sadly I don't have access to a non-local server. The local server application I'm using is MAMP (on a Mac) that runs an apache server. @Ba It is previously defined (see my response to TheGiantBeast @Esailija Using Firebug I looked at the JS console saw no errors. The thing about the request timeline is that under the size of request column it gave a size of something like 300B, but under the content column it had 0B could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "usr" variable is empty (it's a javascript not php), can you show us how to retrieve that variable?

Comment: If var is empty, key anyway will be POSTed but with null or false value. isset() will return true, but showing PHP snippet will help to figure it out.

Comment: It's defined previously `var usr = $('#username').val();`